# Airy's equation 2nd order ODE

Tags: calculus

Suppose we have the equation 
$$ \frac{ d^2 y}{d z^2}= z\, y $$
 for function $y(z).$

We would like to find the 6 first coefficients of the equation given the boundary conditions

$\dfrac{dy}{dz}=1$ at $ z=0,y=2,\,  y(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+a_3z^3+...+a_5z^5.$

I've arrived at the recurrence relation

$$a_{k+3}=\frac{a_k}{(k+3)(k+2)} $$

Can anyone kindly help me with this? Would be really grateful.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way I know to get at this is to first invoke a little theory and realize that, since the equation

$\dfrac{d^2y}{dz^2} = zy \tag 1$

is analytic, so will be the solution; thus the solution will be given by its Taylor series at $z = 0$, so to obtain the $a_i$ in

$y(z) =\displaystyle \sum_0^\infty a_i z^i = \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{y^{(i)}(0)}{i!} z^i, \tag 2$

we need to calculate

$a_i = \dfrac{y^{(i)}(0)}{i!}, \tag 3$

where

$y^{(i)}(0) = \dfrac{d^iy}{dz^i}(0). \tag 4$

We are given that

$y^{(0)}(0) = y(0) = 2, \tag 5$

$y^{(1)}(0) = \dfrac{dy}{dz}(0) = 1, \tag 6$

from which, *via* (1), it readily follows that

$y^{(2)}(0) = \dfrac{d^2y}{dz^2}(0) = 0y(0) = 0(2) = 0; \tag 7$

we may find $y^{(3)}(0)$ from (1) by differentiation:

$y^{(3)}(0) = \dfrac{d^3y}{dz^3}(0) = \dfrac{d}{dz} \dfrac{d^2y}{dz^2}(0) = \dfrac{d}{dz}(zy)(0) = y(0) + (zy^{(1)})(0) = 2 + 0(1) = 2; \tag 8$

likewise, since for any $z$,

$y^{(3)}(z) = y(z) + z y^{(1)}(z), \tag 9$

we have

$y^{(4)}(z) = y^{(1)}(z) + y^{(1)}(z) + z y^{(2)}(z) = 2y^{(1)}(z) + z y^{(2)}(z), \tag{10}$

$y^{(5)}(z) = 2y^{(2)}(z) +  y^{(2)}(z) + zy^{(3)}(z) = 3y^{(2)}(z) + zy^{(3)}(z), \tag{11}$

$y^{(6)}(z) = 3y^{(3)}(z) +  y^{(3)}(z) + zy^{(4)}(z) = 4y^{(3)}(z) + zy^{(4)}(z); \tag{12}$

indeed, it follows easily by induction, taking any of (9)-(12) as a basis, that for $k \ge 3$,

$y^{(k)}(z) = (k - 2)y^{(k - 3)}(z) + zy^{(k - 2)}(z), \tag{13}$

for if we differentiate (13) with respect to $z$, we find

$y^{(k + 1)}(z) = (k - 2) y^{(k - 2)}(z) + y^{(k - 2)} + zy^{(k - 1)}(z) = (k - 1)y^{(k - 2)}(z) + zy^{(k - 1)}(z)$
$= ((k + 1) - 2)y^{((k + 1) - 3)}(z) + zy^{((k + 1) - 2)}(z), \tag{14}$

which agrees with (13) under the substitution $k \to k + 1$.  We may thus recursively evaluate the $y^{(k)}(0)$, and hence the Taylor coefficients $y^{(k)}(0) / k!$, *via* repeated application of (13).

Our OP user496975 asked for the first six coefficients of the series (2); thus we have

$a_0 = y^{(0)}(0) = 2, \tag{15}$

$a_1 = y^{(1)}(0) = 1, \tag{16}$

$a_2 = \dfrac{1}{2}y^{(2)}(0) = 0, \tag{17}$

$a_3 = \dfrac{1}{6}y^{(3)}(0) = \dfrac{2}{6} = \dfrac{1}{3}, \tag{18}$

$a_4 = \dfrac{1}{24}y^{(4)}(0) = \dfrac{2}{24}y^{(1)}(0) =\dfrac{1}{12}, \tag{19}$

$a_5 = \dfrac{1}{120}y^{(5)}(0) = \dfrac{3}{120}y^{(2)}(0) = 0; \tag{20}$

$a_0$-$a_5$ cover the first six terms of the series (2); we throw in a few more for good measure:

$a_6 = \dfrac{1}{720}y^{(6)}(0) = \dfrac{4}{120}y^{(3)}(0) = \dfrac{8}{120} = \dfrac{1}{15}, \tag{21}$

$a_7 = \dfrac{1}{5040}y^{(7)}(0) = \dfrac{5}{5040}y^{(4)}(0) = \dfrac{2}{1008} = \dfrac{1}{504} \tag{22}$

$a_8 = \dfrac{1}{40320}y^{(8)}(0) = \dfrac{6}{40320}y^{(5)}(0) = 0; \tag{23}$

we thus may present the first six non-zero terms of the series for $y(z)$, expanded about $z = 0$:

$y(z) = \sum_0^8 a_i z^i = 2 + z + \dfrac{1}{3}z^3 + \dfrac{1}{12}z^4 + \dfrac{1}{15}z^6 + \dfrac{1}{504}z^7 + \ldots.  \tag{24}$

Finally, we observe the formula (13) undergoes considerable simplification at $z = 0$, becoming

$y^{(k)}(0) = (k - 2)y^{(k - 3)}(0); \tag{25}$

we also observe that we may take $k = 3l + j$, with $j \in \{ 0, 1, 2 \}$,
and continue the pattern initiated in (25):

$y^{(k)}(0) = (k - 2)y^{(k - 3)}(0) = (k - 2)(k - 5)y^{(k - 6)}(0) = (k - 2)(k - 5)(k - 8)y^{(k - 9)}(0)$
$= \ldots = \displaystyle (\prod_0^l (k - 2 - 3i))y^{(j)}(0); \tag{26}$

using (5)-(7), (26) yields

$y^{(k)}(0) = 2\displaystyle \prod_0^l (k - 2 - 3i) \; \text{for}\; k \cong 0 \; \text{mod}(3), \tag{27}$

$y^{(k)}(0) = \displaystyle \prod_0^l (k - 2 - 3i) \; \text{for}\; k \cong 1 \; \text{mod}(3), \tag{28}$

$y^{(k)}(0) = 0 \; \text{for}\; k \cong 2 \; \text{mod}(3); \tag{28}$

and of course in all cases we have

$a_k = \dfrac{y^{(k)}(0)}{k!}. \tag{29}$

Answer (score 0):

You have a third order recurrence relation for the coefficients. Since the recursion is third order, it needs three initial conditions. $a_0$ and $a_1$ come directly from $y(0),y'(0)$. (If you had different boundary conditions, the problem would turn out differently.)

To find $a_2$, notice that putting the expansion into the equation gives you $2a_2=za_0$ at lowest order. Since Frobenius expansion is supposed to work in a neighborhood of $z=0$, you can in particular send $z \to 0$ in this equation to deduce what $a_2$ must be. Then you have all three initial conditions for the recurrence and you can iterate to solve it.

Comment: I want to solve this using series and recurrence relation.

Comment: @user496975 I know, I told you how to do it.

Comment: I have made my initial guess using the sum of akz^k from k=0 to infinity. I've taken this and the second derivative, subed in, shifted the index and arrived at the above written recurrence relation. How do I go about solving the rest?

Comment: @user496975 You start by finding the initial conditions for the recursion. Two of them are trivial, they follow from the given initial conditions. The third one you need to find the way I said here (which is a nontrivial feature of this particular equation). Once you have the initial conditions you *could* hope for an explicit solution to the recurrence, but you could also solve your problem of obtaining some finite number of coefficients by just iterating the recurrence.

Comment: I get it but then a2 should be 0 right?

Comment: @user496975 That's right.